# Where can we find a copy of the "sakila" toy database with uncorrupted city names?

Tags: mysql, corruption, encoding

The "sakila" toy database which is available by download as https://downloads.mysql.com/docs/sakila-db.zip from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/index-other.html contains a `city` table whose city names have undergone corruption due to what I presume were encoding missteps that happened during the lifetime of the file.

For example, the world database (which is the ancestor of the sakila database) available from that same download page has a `city` table with correctly spelled cities such as `A Coruña (La Coruña)` (in Spain), `Acuña` (in Mexico), and `Balašiha` (in Russia), but sakila's `city` table has `A Corua (La Corua)`, `Acua`, and `Balaiha` respectively. Based on my cursory comparison of sakila's `city` table with world's `city` table, these are some of the extended characters that are absent from city names in the sakila table:

> á, â, ç, é, İ, í, ñ, ó, ö, š

Where can a copy of the sakila database with correctly spelled cities be found, if not from mysql.com?

Comment: What about using a CSV file like [from here](https://simplemaps.com/data/world-cities)?

Comment: Thanks, @danblack. I want to complete some exercises with the sakila db specifically. I wondered if db people here know of other authoritative sources for standard toy dbs like sakila (or pagila, dvdrental, etc.) that might have an uncorrupted version.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the LOAD DATA command did not correctly specify the incoming encoding (`CHARACTER SET`).

**More**

Looking at the data file, I conclude that the accented characters are not there.  That is, the problem is not with your actions, but with the source data.

```
# hexdump -C sakila-data.sql | egrep -1 'A Coru|a c|una' | head;
00003850  73 74 20 41 76 65 6e 75  65 27 2c 27 27 2c 27 4b  |st Avenue','','K|
00003860  61 64 75 6e 61 27 2c 32  35 32 2c 27 34 33 33 33  |aduna',252,'4333|
00003870  31 27 2c 27 37 34 37 37  39 31 35 39 34 30 36 39  |1','747791594069|
--
00003a10  35 20 32 32 3a 33 32 3a  33 30 27 29 2c 0a 28 32  |5 22:32:30'),.(2|
00003a20  35 2c 27 32 36 32 20 41  20 43 6f 72 75 61 20 28  |5,'262 A Corua (|
00003a30  4c 61 20 43 6f 72 75 61  29 20 50 61 72 6b 77 61  |La Corua) Parkwa|
```

And that goes back to your original question of "where is a good copy?"

I see that a bug report has been created:

```
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=106951
```

Comment: Interesting idea. I opened sakila-data.sql in a text editor, and the INSERT INTO statements for the city table already have the corrupted city names there. So there’s no way to recover the correct names from these files.

Comment: Did you save the data from the editor?  That could have changed the format.  Can you get the hex of one of the mangled strings -- starting with the CSV file, then any other place you can do it.

Comment: Didn't save the data, opened it carefully. Looks like the damage happened there a while ago and nobody noticed (or cared).

Comment: Is the file corrupted?  Or maybe the text editor mangled it??  Hence, my request for hex.  Point me at the data; I will try to figure out.

Comment: Thanks @Rick! In this zip, look at sakila-data.sql (which is a text file as you probably already know):    https://downloads.mysql.com/docs/sakila-db.zip

Comment: Please do `SHOW CREATE DATABASE sakila;`  I'm especially curious what charset was applied to the database itself.  Also  `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';`

Comment: @Rick_James I freshly installed MySQL to explore this issue with 3 sakila archives, one from mysql.com and two from other sites. I installed mysql with charset utf8mb4 and collation utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci. The result for `show create database` for all 3 is `CREATE DATABASE sakila /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci */`. All 3 copies of sakila have `SET NAMES utf8mb4;` as the first statement in sakila-schema.sql and in sakila-data.sql. @Rick_James when you unzip https://downloads.mysql.com/docs/sakila-db.zip do you see anything helpful in the .sql files? Thanks again

Comment: @TimStewart - If that is the same source as your previous link, I found that the tilda-n character was totally missing, even without touching MySQL.  Instead, I used hexdump to determine that the zip is wrong.  (And I seriously doubt if "zip" is at fault.)

Comment: @Rick_James that matches my observations. Glad to see a bug report is in.

Answer (score 1):

The database dump file `mysql-examples-8.0.28.msi` which is available from https://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/MySQLInstaller/mysql-examples-8.0.28.msi is already damaged.

If you need in city names only then download `world` sample database.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-shell-tutorial-python-download.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-shell-tutorial-javascript-download.html

Also you may try to download "Samples and Examples" file via MySQl Installer for some ancient version.